# The C compiler cl.exe is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake, vtk, qt6

I'm trying to set up VTK with cmake visual studio 16 2019 and Qt 6,
But when i try to configure cmake i have the following pb :

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29337.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29337.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:48 (try_compile):
  Failed to open

    C:/Users/mathi/Documents/VTK/VTK-9.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt

  Permission denied
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:26 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (project)


Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:53 (try_compile):
  Failed to open

    C:/Users/mathi/Documents/VTK/VTK-9.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt

  Permission denied
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (project)


Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/mathi/Documents/VTK/VTK-9.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/mathi/Documents/VTK/VTK-9.0.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Can you try building from scratch ?

Comment: Seems like a permission problem (if the files exists). Perhaps you build  VTK as administrator and now you are a regular user

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm stuck on the exact same issue